# How can I detect with Web3.js a NET change in Metamask navigator plugin?

Tags: web3js, metamask

How can I detect with Web3.js a NET change in Metamask navigator plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the 'chainChanged' [Metamask](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#events) method.

```
ethereum.on('chainChanged', (_chainId) => window.location.reload());
```

or

```
window.ethereum.on('chainChanged', function (accounts) {
    window.location.reload(); //or your own code
});
```